# UITableView non-using Navigation control

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Can I not use Navigation control to switch my UIViewController?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
 BATTrailsViewController *trailsController = [[BATTrailsViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
 trailsController.selectedRegion = [regions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:trailsController animated:YES];
}
```

Can I do this without using `[[self navigationController] pushViewController:trailsController animated:YES];`??

I want my UITableView selectrow to a new UIViewController without navigation.

Comment: haha,solved my stupid question,Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
[self presentViewController:animated:completion];
```

Hope this helps.